# Get nextvalue from Oracle Sequence which is dynamically generated and in form of varchar2 or string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sequence

I am dynamically creating sequence based on few combinations. How would i get `nextVal` from this dynamicaly generated Sequence ?

```
declare

loc_cd varchar2(10);
gr_cd varchar2(10);
seqval number;
seq varchar2(2000);
st varchar2(2000);
v_select varchar2(2000);
begin

loc_cd :='12345';
gr_cd :='99';

seq := 'SE'||loc_cd||gr_cd; 
dbms_output.put_line(seq);

 st := 'create sequence ' ||seq|| ' minvalue 1 maxvalue 99999999999 start with 1 increment by 1 cache 20' ;
dbms_output.put_line(st);
execute immediate st;
dbms_output.put_line('seq created'); 


v_select := 'select '||seq||'.nextval from dual';
execute immediate v_select into seqval; 
dbms_output.put_line(seqval); --This is ok


  dbms_output.put_line( seq.nextval);  -- This is not. how to achieve this ?
end;
```

I have problem in using  `seq.nextval` Getting error `** Invalid refrence to variable SEQ .**`

I don't want to use below

```
v_select := 'select '||seq||'.nextval from dual';
        execute immediate v_select into seqval;
```

**EDIT for More Clarification what I want to achieve**

I have a tableA with columns CONS_NO, LOC_CD, GR_NO and SRNO, having thousands records. CONS_NO have unique records, LOC_CD and GR_NO have same value say 12345 and 94 for  SRNO value from 1 to 1000., then another set of LOC_CD and GR_NO say 67890 and 95  with SRNO 1 t0 1000 with unqiue CONS_NO and so on.

I need to prcoess these sets of LOC_CD and GR_NO in multithread using Java. For ex, a set of LOC_CD & GR_NO with value 12345 and 94  (having 1000 records in tableA) will be process in 10 threads (number of records per thread being 100). Each thread will call a procedure INSERTPROC. Befor calling multithread for a set of LOC_CD and GR_NO, I am dynamicly creating sequecne say SE1234594 and for another set SE6789095 and so on....

for set1 of LOC_CD and GR_NO, calls from Java multithread would be like..

```
seq SE1234594 created 
procedure  INSERTPROC('12345', '94', 1,  100)
procedure  INSERTPROC('12345', '94', 101,  200) 
.....
procedure  INSERTPROC('12345', '94', 901,  1000)
seq SE1234594 dropped.
```

for set2 of LOC_CD and GR_NO 67890 95 calls from Java multithread would be like..

```
seq SE6789095 created 

procedure  INSERTPROC('67890', '95', 1,  100)
procedure  INSERTPROC('67890', '95', 101,  200) 
.....
procedure  INSERTPROC('67890', '95', 901,  1000)
seq SE6789095 dropped
```

The structure of  INSERTPROC is something as below

```
procedure INSERTPROC(loc_cd  IN VARCHAR2, gr_cd IN VARCHAR2, countstrt number, countend number) as 
--declration part
begin

insert into tab3 (sr_no, col1, col2)
  (select 'SE'||loc_cd||gr_cd.nextval, --how to use seq here ?
          col1,
          col2 from (select col1, col2 from tableA a, tab1 b   where  a.SRNO  between countstrt and countend /*some more condition */           
                )  
   )
end ;
```

**My Question**: How can I use sequence  which is dynamicaly generated thru Java code and is combination of LOC_CD and GR_NO in the procdedure INSERTPROC

Unfortunately i cannt use rownum and autoincrement on table tab3 as rownum is generating same sr_no if proc runs in parallel threads, autoincrment will not starts with 1 for next set of multi thread call for LOC_CD and GR_NO.)

Comment: Your sequence is not created yet, so the PL/SQL block will fail to compile as it finds no sequence with that name. It's a compile time error message by Oracle that checks if  all the referenced dependant objects are indeed present.

Comment: @KaushikNayak , even if I am using already created sequence, I am getting same error.  loc_cd :='12345';
gr_cd :='94'; seq := 'SE'||loc_cd||gr_cd;  dbms_output.put_line(seq.nextval);  But if i use the name directly   SE1234594.nextvalu   it works...

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can't refer to the object names(table,sequence etc) and column names through variables directly, `execute immediate` is designed for such operation.

Comment: Actually I have a proc (insertproc) which gets called from java in multithreads. this proc does the insert something like below, here loc_cd and gr_cd are the inputs to the proc, using these inputs I need to get nextval of sequence. unfortunately i cannt use rownum and autoincrement as rownum is generating same sr_no if proc runs in parallel threads, autoincrment will not starts with 1 for next set of multi thread call.

Comment: procedure insertproc (loc_cd  IN VARCHAR2, gr_cd IN VARCHAR2, countstrt in number, countend in number) as 
--declration part
begin
insert into tab3 (sr_no, col1, col2)
  (select 'SE'||loc_cd||gr_cd.nextval, 
          col1,
          col2 (select col1, col2 from tab1 a, tab2 b where b.counnum between countstrt and countend  /*some more condition */                
                )  
   )
end ;

Comment: Don't add details as comments, it is barely readable. Edit your question and add the relevant details explaining in detail the issue you are facing. See the edit button below the tags .

Comment: @KaushikNayak , please see the edit.

Comment: Why not select  `a.SRNO` itself in the  insert statement to populate `tab3.sr_no` , aren't those numbers going to be same ?

Comment: a.SRNO would be same for each thread number , hence I will get duplicate values tab3.sr_no.  I want to have unique SR_NO for tab3 as well.

Comment: I may not have fully understood your application yet, but it's still not clear to me how do you decide the start and end values of the dynamic sequence you create for each set

Comment: From what I can infer, you need only one sequence, let's call it `tab3_seq` exclusive for incrementing values in `tab3` alone and in your procedure simply use `tab3_seq.nextval`  in the insert statement. Oracle will automatically handle the rest of the concurrency problems for your threads.

Comment: @KaushikNayak , Pls check my answer. Not sure if this is the best way to achieve. And yes, I had to use execute immediate. I had no other option :)

Comment: The method you come up with is not at all a feasible solution. Looping through the records is sub-optimal and is going to cause performance issues now or later, especially since yours is a multi-threaded approach. It seems that's just a workaround to fix the problem at hand rather than finding a fool-proof solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve what I want by creating a proc which brings me `nextval` from dynamicaly created sequence.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE callSeq(
 seqname IN varchar2,
 seqval OUT number
 )
IS

v_select varchar2(1000);

BEGIN

   v_select := 'select '||seqname||'.nextval from dual';
   execute immediate v_select into seqval;
   /*  dbms_output.put_line(seqval);*/


END;
```

and using this proc in my INSERTPROC as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPROC(LOC_CD  IN VARCHAR2,
                                             GR_CD IN VARCHAR2,                                                 
                                            countstrt in number, countend in number

                                             ) is

declare
 seqval number;
BEGIN 
   FOR c IN  (select LOC_CD, GR_CD  from tableA a, tab1 b   where  a.SRNO  between countstrt and countend /*some more condition */           
                )  
     LOOP
     callSeq('SE'||c.LOC_CD||c.GR_CD,seqval) ;
 insert into tab3 (col1, col2, sr_no) values(c.LC_CD, c.GR_CD ,seqval) ;          
   END LOOP;  
END;
```

Though this process degrade the overall Performamnce. But it still OK. Any other suggestion to Original solution are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a single sequence `tab3_seq` exclusively for `tab3` and let Oracle take care of concurrent threads using the same sequence.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertproc (
     loc_cd      IN VARCHAR2,
     gr_cd       IN VARCHAR2,
     countstrt   IN NUMBER,
     countend    IN NUMBER
) IS

BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tab3 (
          sr_no,
          col1,
          col2
     )
          SELECT tab3_seq.NEXTVAL, -- This will not overlap while being used by multiple sessions  
                 col1,
                 col2
          FROM tablea a
          JOIN             --Use proper Join syntax rather than obsolete a,b syntax 
           tab1 b ON ( a.id = b.id ) --your Join condition 
          WHERE a.srno BETWEEN countstrt AND countend /*some more condition */
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it gives 111111ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object, when  more than one set of instances of threads runs parallel for two different set of loc_cd and gr_cd paralley.

Comment: @Manish Suriya : You have to create the sequence only once and that should be independent of the procedure  or threads. It seems you are trying to create the same sequence 2 or more times

Comment: If I  will not create new seq for new set of loc_cd and gr_no, the sr_no would not strt from 1. and I want the srno from 1 for every set of loc_cd and gr_no

Comment: @Manish Suriya : But, in one of  your comment you said " I want to have unique SR_NO for tab3 as well" . Did you mean you want it unique in tab3 across a set and not across the table?

Comment: @ManishSuriya : Ok, thanks that you clarified. It means you could use ROWNUM + countstrt as sr_no right (and not simply ROWNUM as you already tried )?